# Django: URL doesn't match view function

Tags: python, django

I have my URL defined as follows:

```
(r'^article/edit/(.*)/$', 'mysite.views.edit_article')
```

And the function defined as:

```
def edit_article(request, article_id):
```

However, it seems that any request to this page results in the wrong value being passed in for article_id. If I redefine my URL as

```
(r'^article/(.*)/$', 'mysite.views.edit_article')
```

Minus the "edit/" it seems to work. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: What "wrong value" are you getting?

Comment: In what way is it wrong? What is the actual value for `article_id` vs the expected value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
url (r'^article/edit/(?P<article_id>\d+)$', 'mysite.views.edit_article'),
```

Take a look at the [Named Groups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#named-groups) in the Django documentation

Comment: You don't *have* to name the parameter - if you don't, it will be passed positionally, to the first argument in the function (after request). Since his view only has one additional argument, it should work either way.